# Insufficient Privileges When Creating AAD App via Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am running into an issue while trying to create an AAD app through the Microsoft Graph beta endpoint (`/beta/applications`).

I am using an AAD app that has the application permission `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and has been consented by a tenant admin.

Using the `client_credentials` flow, I obtain a token that when decoded shows that it contains:

```
"roles": [
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All"
]
```

However, when I `POST` to `/beta/applications`, I get the following response:

```json
{
    'error': {
        'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
        'innerError': {
            'date': '2018-02-06T20:59:16',
            'request-id': '02f77ca4-1634-426d-9235-cc0c109b0283'
        },
        'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'
    }
}
```

Could someone help me figure out what is going on?

EDIT: code used to obtain token

```
tenant = 'michaelzlat.onmicrosoft.com' 
url = f'login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token' 
data = { 
    'scope': 'graph.microsoft.com/.default', 
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 
    'client_id': client_id, 
    'client_secret': secret 
} 
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to obtain the token? Also, what is the body of your request?

Comment: Added the code to the question above. Regarding the body of the request (assuming you mean to the /applications), I've tried a variety of options, but even the simplest {'displayName': someTestDisplayName} fails. It might also be worth noting that I am able to GET /applications with this token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry - the documentation on [application creation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications) is incorrect and needs to be fixed.  You'll need to use `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permission.  There currently is no application permission (for client_credentials flow) that supports application creation. If you need this support please file a request for this feature on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

What's your scenario for creating an application in application-only mode?

**EDIT based on conversation:**
Sorry for the late response. If I understand correctly, you'll be creating a multi-tenant app for each snippet, in the ScriptLab tenant.  That way users from multiple tenants could try out (and consent to) any snippet that is posted.  Each user would still need to consent to allow the snippet access to their data - assuming for now the APIs the snippets use only require user consent.  So in the ScriptLab tenant you need to be able to create and manage config of many apps (on behalf of different folks - although not sure about the authz here).

For now your ScriptLab app could create and manage multiple apps using the *Directory.AccessAsUser.All* permission (and using offline access mode), granted by an admin and running in their (or another ScriptLab tenant user's) context. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference for more details on available permissions for Microsoft Graph.  This is a workaround for Graph not supporting app-only permissions for app management (for now).  Also please note that the application API in Microsoft Graph is only available in /beta and is subject to change, which could break your application.

An alternative is to use Azure AD Graph.  While not documented, Azure AD Graph supports an app-only permission called *Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy* (Manage apps that this app creates and owns). You can see the permission in the Azure Portal.  If you configure your app with this permission (and grant it), then your app will be able to create apps and configure them.  We just haven't got around to porting this permission to Microsoft Graph.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Within [ScriptLab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/), we'd like to be able to get Graph access tokens to allow users of any tenant to run their own "snippets" against documents stored on OneDrive through Graph. Since the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission requires admin consent, the approach we were going with was creating multi-tenant AAD apps on ScriptLab's tenant to tie to each snippet. Is there another way to accomplish this?